# Intellij is applying java level 1.5 even though 1.8 selected in four places

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Where is IJ picking up the language level ??  When compiling I am getting the following error:

```
Error:(29, 38) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

Note: the pom.xml has NO mention of the java level.

But from screenshots we see **FOUR** places I have selected 1.8 !

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this maven project ?

Comment: I added to the OP that the pom.xml has no language level specified.

Comment: @JigarJoshi  Please re-post your (correct) answer.  I had updated the scala-maven plugin. After updating the maven-compiler it does fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place following in your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

IntelliJ respects's maven pom.xml's configuration, by default points to JAVA_HOME and which might not be set properly, So setting compiler version to 1.8 does the job here

Comment: Before you added this I already had tried adding source/target. No change: same error.  Actually no - i had updated the scala-maven plugin. After updating the maven-compiler it does fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Settings > Modules > {module} > Dependencies > Module SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Please see screen shot attached.[image: one language level settings]

Comment: Sorry for that, didn't realize it, all of StackOverflow is also white so it seemed ok. Now I can't replace it with more white spaced one :)